# Best way to implement an image Slider

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiswipegesturerecognizer

I am implementing an image `Slider` in my application, I think I know how to do it but in an inefficient way.

I get `URL's` of images ( I do not know the number, can be between 1 or 20, maybe more..) so I have to show then in a `view` and the user can make `Swipe` to pass to the next picture or get back to the picture before.

So, I would like to know if its better to do with `G.C.D` and `blocks`, or with out it. if it is with `GCD`. Should I fill and `NSMutableData` with downloaded images to the `UIview` and then make `swipe`..? is better if the picture is downloaded after each `swipe gesture`?

I do not know how to manage this. Any ideas?

Comment: you can use sdwebimage library or can download image asynchronously and till the image load show a activity indicator.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to hold multiple large images in memory at the same time. You've got 2 problems to solve: 1. Downloading the image asynchronously, and loading them one at a time.

The way to download the images is to use NSURLConnection. There is a new class method in NSURLConnection (sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler:, added in iOS 5) that will download the entire file and invoke a block once it's done. It's easier to use than code that creates a connection and handles the various delegate methods.

You can start multiple downloads at once and the system takes care of managing them. I would suggest doing no more than 3 at a time however.

The second problem is how to display the images. I would suggest using a UIPageViewController with the transition style UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyleScroll.

If your images are big enough then you should really tile them.

There is a sample app from Apple in the Xcode docs called PhotoScroller. It shows how to handle multiple large images using a UIPageViewController and image tiling. If your images aren't that big then tiling might be overkill. Dealing with tiled images is certainly complex.

Comment: I must show images in a small UIImageView with 320,200 size and I should can make the swipe there and also press the image and watch it in full screen. I use for all the requests AFNetworking Library so, I guess is better to keep using it. I like your proposals, I'll try to use it with AFNetworking